# Trying to use CiviCRM to take memberships for an event

Tags: civimember, cividiscount

I've been looking at CiviCRM to see if it would work for running an event in about 3 years time.

I'm pretty new to CiviCRM. The event is a convention and is a one off. People can join many years ahead and their membership is effectively lifetime.  I'm trying to set up a membership system that lets you join as one member type, then upgrade. Using a contributions page, I'm just adding the membership types for their prices. (I'm also using CiviDiscount to discount your upgrade). You can successfully upgrade, BUT it then keeps showing you the lower tier memberships. And you can choose them... Is there a way of not having them show up?

I'm glad to be pointed at educational resources. And glad to change code, but I'm not sure where.

I realise that this isn't really what CiviCRM is designed for. But the other features are so useful, that really if I can get past the membership problems I'm having, it may be worth it.

Thanks,
Norman

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the price options to hide lower-tier memberships with a custom extension.  This is a more maintainable alternative to editing the code directly, since it will work through an upgrade.

Check the [docs for creating extensions](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/) and install `civix`.  Then use the [buildAmount hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/stable/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildAmount/) to edit the price sets.  Some folks think this is easier with the [buildForm hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/stable/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm); you may want to try both.

Comment: OK, thanks. Something for my future then... :-)